# How does grep match directory URLs?

Tags: url, grep

This is a .xml file that stores a large number of URLs and it is as follows.

```
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/en/rWGpqHtU/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/de/hVHaViPm/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/uk/ysbqqLRj/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/jp/EUvnikfR/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/hk/UqGauZTv/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
```

How do I match the url that starts with `http://www.example.com/uk/` and `http://www.example.com/hk/`?

This is what I've tried so far and it will match all URLs.

```
cat sitemap.xml | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -Eo 'https?://www\.example\.com/[uh]k/[^<]*'
```

Here, `-E` enables POSIX ERE syntax, and the  pattern matches:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `www\.example\.com/` - `www.example.com/`
- `[uh]k/` - `uk/` or `hk/`
- `[^<]*` - 0 or more chars other than `<`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8hVRE8):

```
#!/bin/bash
xml='<url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/en/rWGpqHtU/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/de/hVHaViPm/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/uk/ysbqqLRj/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/jp/EUvnikfR/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/hk/UqGauZTv/</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq></url>'
grep -Eo "https?://www\.example\.com/[uh]k/[^<]*" <<< "$xml"
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/uk/ysbqqLRj/
http://www.example.com/hk/UqGauZTv/
```

Comment: Excuse me, can I ask one more question? How do I match Level 3 directories? Like this: `http://www.example.com/uk/xxx/xxx/`

Comment: @Lorraine1996 `https?://www\.example\.com/[uh]k/[^/]+/[^/]+`?

Comment: It seems to have some problems, can you look at it? Ideally it will only match 3 level directory URLs. [Online demo](https://ideone.com/bZ7DWo)

Comment: @Lorraine1996 Try `grep -Eo "https?://www\.example\.com/[uh]k/[^/<]+/[^/<]+"`